# Jetpack compose with two Navigation Host, hot to go back without without recompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Basically, I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav),
So here's my screen:

```
    @Composable
    fun myscreen(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(

      bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation {
          val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
          val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
          items.forEach { screen ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
              icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
              label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
              selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
              onClick = {
                navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                  // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                  // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                  // on the back stack as users select items
                  popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    saveState = true
                  }
                  // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                  // reselecting the same item
                  launchSingleTop = true
                  // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                  restoreState = true
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
    ) { innerPadding ->
      NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.Profile.route, Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
        composable(Screen.Profile.route) { Profile(navController) }
        composable(Screen.FriendsList.route) { FriendsList(navController) }
      }
    }
    }

This goes inside MyActivity that has navhost too

    class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
          val navhost = rememberNavController()
      
          ApplicationTheme {
            Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
              NavHost(navhost , startDestination = "myscreen") {
                composable("myscreen")    {  myscreen() }
                composable("signupscreen") { signupscreen(navhost ) }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now if if navigate from myscreen to other different composable,
when pressing back from that composable, myscreen is recomposed.
but inside myscreen when i move between screens, nothing recomposed  and that behavior i want when back to myscreen from other composable

Code for pressing back button from other composable

```
 navhost.navigateUp()
```

Comment: Recomposition is not something bad. And in this case there's nothing you can do to prevent it - the screen was unloaded and should be re-loaded again. You're not storing your data correctly. I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles. Also if you'll update your question with how you store it right now, I'll be able to give you a more accurate advice